# HDMI Development: What Would Cause Thin Pink Lines?

Tags: pcb-design, display, hdmi

I recently designed a board which produces an HDMI output for an oscilloscope so it is viewable on an external monitor. My prototypes seemed to work just fine with one or two mod wires. However, after adding these mods to the copper and re-spinning the board, I am getting fine pink vertical lines spaced evenly across the entire screen, mostly visible in the white areas:

[image]
It's a bit difficult to see in the above image, but you can see it if you zoom in on the white line just above the blue language ribbon, and also in the white arrow beneath the "Training Signals" text.

It can also be seen in some of the text, as in the image below:

[image]

The lines appear to be approximately 10 pixels from the start of one to the start of the next. The video format is 800 x 600 @ 60Hz.

I have tried reflowing the solder joints, re-cleaning the board, baking it, etc but I am still seeing the issue. At this point I am fairly confident that it is not a connection issue and instead has something to do with the display data itself, be it timing or something else altogether.

What would cause such evenly-spaced pink lines to appear on an HDMI monitor? In case it is important, I am using a Xilinx FPGA as the controller, some Cypress SRAM for the frame buffer, and the TFP410 for the HDMI transmitter.

Comment: Check FPGA timing reports on pins associated with the green channel. Maybe P&R with tighter I/O constraints. Also try higher quality HDMI cables, it's one case in AV where poor cables can cause catastroptic failures. (yes that's a typo. But it fits...)

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions. Unfortunately probing the FPGA pins to get the signal timing would be quite difficult, I'm not exactly sure how I'd do that. I do not have control over the FPGA pinouts because that is determined by the oscilloscope motherboard. HDMI routing was done carefully to match propagation delay and transmitter/receiver impedances. I can certainly try a different cable, and in fact I'm not sure why I didn't do that to begin with. I will post back here with the results.

Comment: Most likely data is not stable or ready at sampling edge. Or color sampling issue. Are you using 4:4:4 RGB throughout the design or is the video ever converted to YCbCr 4:2:2 at some stage? Is this really HDMI protocol or DVI protocol? Edit: nevermind, TFP410 means it is DVI so it can't be HDMI and officially you are not allowed to use HDMI connector. Also try another monitor and check that timings are pixel-exact and sync polarity is correct.

Comment: @Justme It's full 4:4:4 RGB. TFP410 does HDMI (at least according to the datasheet) though you're right, I haven't gone through any of the proper channels to get it approved/licensed as actual HDMI. That being said, my understanding is that making a XXX-to-HDMI *cable* is not legal, whereas making dongles or devices with HDMI connectors without licensing is fine as long as I don't officially call it "HDMI". They have no rights over the connector itself, to my knowledge.

Comment: TFP410 is for DVI protocol only, it has no way whatsoever of emitting HDMI protocol. I don't say what is legal or not, but some sources say you need a licence to implement HDMI into a product or component. That's why some hobbyists sell devices with DVI connector, and a build-it-yourself version might have HDMI connector to avoid any issues. They also say officially approved connectors must be used in official products. Well, unofficial products can use any connectors then. Should be fine if you don't call it HDMI.

Comment: There are countless examples on the web of the TFP410 being used in HDMI applications. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the difference between HDMI and DVI, but I have found literally hundreds of sources of this device being used to generate TMDS signals used to connect to an HDMI monitor over an HDMI cable.

I will have to be careful about not actually using the term "HDMI"

Comment: HDMI devices are required to receive DVI protocol. That still does not make TFP410 a HDMI transmitter. It will transmit video only, with DVI protocol, without HDMI protocol, metadata and audio. So, is the display really a monitor or a TV? Some HDMI TVs consider all data as being smooth video instead of sharp computer graphics so they assume they can convert all data internally to 4:2:2 for processing, so graphics will lose quality.

Comment: @Justme Ah, I see. So far I have plugged it into an external HDMI monitor, and I was aware that it was video only (no audio, since that's not supported by DVI 1.0). I have not connected this device to an actual television. Regardless, this does not explain why the lines are only appearing now, and they weren't appearing on earlier prototypes which were nearly identical in design.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I wasn't suggesting probing : however you can deliberately add capacitive loading to selected pins ... if one makes the problem worse, you have a likely culprit. What I WAS suggesting involved the static timing analysis tools after FPGA place and route, and the pin constraint files. For example, tighten the pin setup/hold times (and maybe clock speed) and re-run timing checks. Note which pins fail. If they are green, you know where to focus.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ah, that I don't have control over. The FPGA is programmed by the host device (the scope) on power-up. I do not have access to any of the programming, unfortunately.

Comment: I will probably end up simply building a second board to see if it exhibits the same behavior. That should give me an idea of whether it is a hardware issue or a software/firmware issue.